Numbering heading using #show - Typst
When I started using the show method in Typst, I lost the heading numbering.
How can i get it back?
#show heading: it => [
    #block(fill:white, outset: 5pt, radius: 20%, 
    underline(stroke: rgb(39, 174, 96) + 1.5pt, offset: 1.75pt)[#it.body])
]


Your show function uses it.body, so only the heading text (body) is showing. You can fix this by displaying it instead of it.body, which contains information about the numbering:
#set heading(numbering: "1.")
#show heading: it => [
    #block(fill:white, outset: 5pt, radius: 20%, 
    underline(stroke: rgb(39, 174, 96) + 1.5pt, offset: 1.75pt)[#it])
]

= Heading


If you want to also underline the whitespace between the number and heading, you can explicitly display the heading number and body separately:
#set heading(numbering: "1.")
#show heading: it => [
  #block(
    fill: white,
    outset: 5pt,
    radius: 20%,
    underline(stroke: rgb(39, 174, 96) + 1.5pt, offset: 1.75pt)[
      #counter(heading).display() #it.body
    ],
  )
]

= Heading



It resolve my issue, appreciate it. Other concern regarding typst formatting: in my template im using pattern as background. How can i make white box only behind text to avoid dash on the text (https://imgur.com/a/SkbYbnl). Im using showybox for the color boxes but i dont want the text inside to be affected.

You can wrap the text inside block(fill: white) to give it a background. If you have large spacing between lines, you can also use highlight(fill: white)[your text] and the space in between each line will remain transparent.

The issue with the block(fill: white) is that it affect also my grey boxes, is there an option for selecting all text except the ones inside the th(title, text) = showybox(...)?

This would be easier to answer separately. Can you please open a new question and provide example code as you did for this heading issue?
